# Python: Combining numbers in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, processing-efficiency

I have a list, say

```
x = [0,1,2,3,"a","b","cd"]
```

I want to keep the smallest number and all of the letters, hence in the example it would become

```
x = [0,"a","b","cd"]
```

How can I do this? Ideally the code would be very efficient, as I'm doing this for millions of lists.

Attempts: I've tried finding min(x), however it results in an error as there are strings in the list

Comment: You're going to have to write the code yourself... have you tried anything to accomplish your task so far?

Comment: You can pass a `key` to `min`. I think `key=lambda el: el if isinstance(el, int) else sys.maxsize` will work. Obviously you'll have to `import sys`

Comment: `min(filter(lambda x: type(x) == int,x))` although I wouldn't know how efficiency compares with the suggestion from @SyntaxVoid

Comment: Can you change the data at the source? It's unusual to have lists containing both integers and strings. If you can avoid mixing the data together in the first place that'd be best.

Comment: Unfortunately not, although I see why it would be extremely beneficial if I could!

Comment: @gst, I tested it with timeit. Your method with `filter` is about 3-5% faster than mine on shuffled 20000 element lists with 10000 ints and 10000 strings. Probably because of the extra comparison I have to do when hitting a string :-)

Answer (score 6):

I think the below code is most efficient. It does not take extra memory and complexity is O(N)

```
import sys
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "cd"]
minimum = sys.maxsize # for python 3.x
# minimum = sys.maxint #for python 2
j = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    if isinstance(x[i], str):
        x[j] = x[i]
        j+=1
    else:
        minimum = min(minimum, x[i])
print([minimum]+x[:j])
```

Output

```
[0, 'a', 'b', 'cd']
```

Comment: Type checking by `type(object) == desired_type` is unpythonic. Consider using `isinstance(object, desired_type)`. The latter supports inheritance

Answer (score 5):

try this:

Python 2.7

```
output = [s for s in x if isinstance(s, str)]
output.append(min(x))

#>>> output
#['a', 'b', 'cd', 0]
```

Python3:

```
output = [s for s in x if isinstance(s, str)]
output.append(min([i for i in x if isinstance(i, int)]))
```

Comment: Did you run this? You can't use `min` on a list with in-comparable types without getting a TypeError. `'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` in this case

Comment: Yes, I run before submitting , there is no problem using python 2.7.

Comment: Edited for python3. @SyntaxVoid

Comment: I wasn't aware python 2.7 allowed comparing strings and ints. I appreciate the edit!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> x = [0,1,2,3,"a","b","cd"]
>>> [min(n, *g) if t == int else n for t, g in groupby(x, type) for n in g]
[0, 'a', 'b', 'cd']
```

More efficient would be to just min the integers and unpack the strings.

```
>>> x = [0,1,2,3,"a","b","cd"]
>>> grouped = [list(g) for t, g in groupby(x, type)]
>>> [min(grouped[0]), *grouped[1]]
[0, 'a', 'b', 'cd']
```

Comment: this is not the most efficient. this is O(N^2) complexity

Comment: Just added an alternative

Comment: Again you are initializing a list `grouped` which takes O(N) extra space.

Comment: won't work for `list` with mixed numbers & characters, also won't work if characters go first, also not memory efficient

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use the `.isnumeric()` method to find the minimum number while building a new list for the strings. This should be O(n). Not super fast, but not slow either.

You could say something like:

```
min_number = None
string_list = []

for i in x:
    if i.isnumeric():
        if min_number is None or i < min_number:
            min_number = i
    elif isinstance(i, str):
        string_list.append(i)

if min_number is not None:
    x = string_list.insert(0, min_number)
```

Comment: This produces an error as `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'`

Comment: You are taking new list to store data. Which takes extra memory. Here we are looking for efficient solution. Given that list is too large.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this would be the most efficient but you could separate the list into two lists - one with `int`s and one with `string`s - and then find the `min` then rejoin them. This would look something like:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c']
nums = []
strings = []
for item in x:
    if isinstance(item, int):
        nums.append(item)
    else:
        strings.append(item)
```

Now, after you run this, you can get the `min` and then rejoin the lists

```
result = [min(nums)] + chars
```

This will give `[0, 'a', 'b', 'c']`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
def minNum(array):
    min = None
    numPos = []
    for i in array:
        if type(i) == int or type(i) == float:
            if min is None or i < min:
                min = i
                numPos.append(array.index(i))
            else:
                numPos.append(array.index(i))
        else:
            pass
    numPos.reverse()
    for j in numPos:
        if array[j] != min:
            del array[j]
    return array
```

Definitely not the only solution but its fairly compact and works well for all the test cases I gave

Comment: This is certainly a solution, but compact? It's the longest one here by far!

Comment: `type`s are unique, you should be using `is` operator for comparing them, also we have `isinstance` built-in